# Problema con Buffer Visual studio 2019 (fflush(stdin)), acumulacion de preguntas

Tags: c++

**Mi problema es el siguiente, el codigo me sirve en Codeblocks, pero en visual studio 2019 se me rellena el buff y eso que uso el fflush(stdin), no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, y de ser asi, corregirme por favor!**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct alumnos {
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    double promedio;
}alumnos[3];

int main()
{
    double mayor = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl; 
        fflush(stdin);
        cin.getline(alumnos[i].nombre, 20, '\n');
        cout << "Ingrese edad: " << endl; 
        cin >> alumnos[i].edad;
        cout << "Ingrese promedio: " << endl; 
        cin >> alumnos[i].promedio;
        
        if (alumnos[i].promedio > mayor)
        {
            mayor = alumnos[i].promedio;
            j = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nAlumno N." << i << endl;
        cout << "Nombre: " << alumnos[i].nombre << endl;
        cout << "Edad: " << alumnos[i].edad << endl;
        cout << "Promedio: " << alumnos[i].promedio << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n El alumno N. " << j << " " << alumnos[j].nombre << " tiene el Mejor Promedio con: " << alumnos[j].promedio;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La función [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) no limpia el búfer `stdin`, sino, el `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con el vaciado del búfer. Tu problema es que escribes y lees datos fuera de la formación.

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) indexa desde cero. Eso significa que en una formación de tres elementos (como `alumnos[3]`) están disponibles los índices `0`, `1` y `2`. Sin embargo tú recorres los índices `1`, `2` y `3` para rellenar:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl; 
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.getline(alumnos[i].nombre, 20, '\n');
    // ...
}
```

Y para mostrar:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    cout << "\nAlumno N." << i << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: " << alumnos[i].nombre << endl;
    // ...
}
```

Cambia los bucles para que recorran los índices de cero a dos:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl; 
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.getline(alumnos[i].nombre, 20, '\n');
    // ...
}

for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    cout << "\nAlumno N." << i << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: " << alumnos[i].nombre << endl;
    // ...
}
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. No uses formaciones de caracteres para almacenar texto, usa `std::string`:

   ```
   struct alumnos {
       string nombre;
       int edad;
       double promedio;
   }alumnos[3];
   ```
2. Si la estructura almacena un sólo elemento, su nombre debe ser en singular; cualquier otra cosa es confusa:

   ```
   struct alumno {
       string nombre;
       int edad;
       double promedio;
   }alumnos[3];
   ```
3. Puedes sobrecargar el operador de lectura desde flujo de datos para simplificar el código:

   ```
   std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, alumno &a)
   {
       cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl; 
       i.getline(a.nombre);
       cout << "Ingrese edad: " << endl; 
       i >> a.edad;
       cout << "Ingrese promedio: " << endl; 
       i >> a.promedio;
       return i;
   }
   ```
4. Puedes sobrecargar el operador de escritura en flujo de datos para simplificar el código:

   ```
   std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const alumno &a)
   {
       return o << "Nombre: " << a.nombre << endl
                << "Edad: " << a.edad << endl
                << "Promedio: " << a.promedio;
   }
   ```

Con esos consejos, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main()
{
    alumno alumnos[3];

    for (auto &a : alumnos)
        std::cin >> a;

    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        std::cout << "Alumno N. " << (i + 1) << endl << alumnos[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excelente aporte, gracias crack ! , me sirvió, igual solo cambie el char por string  y alli me funciono perfecto, igual tomare en cuenta esos datos ultimos para mejorar el codigo.